# Jquery mobile panel get hide by bxslider carousal

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

I have bxSlider carousal and jquery mobile panel on same page. On swipe right panel opens. Inside panel there link , on click of link which hide current item from pane add new item (all static).

My problem is when panel opens its fine. But when inside panel I click on link new content comes  bxslider show above the panel. panel comes each time but second time hide by carousal.

It is fine in pc only problem in mobile.

Thanks for help..

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bxxloder and JQM</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
 //$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = (screen.availWidth) / 60;
  $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = (screen.availWidth) / 100;        
 //$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = '30'; // default 30px
 $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = '150'; // default 75px
});
</script>
    <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<!--#########################JQM#########################-->
<!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
<div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-theme="b" data-url="demo-page"> <!--start #demo-page-->

    <div data-role="content">


     <!--######################### Panel ##############################-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-theme="b">
    <div id="panelholder"> <!--start panelholder-->
        <p class="menulink" id="menulink1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" /><img src="images/search.png" alt="search" /><br>Search</a></p>
        <p class="menulink" id="menulink2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" /><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share" /><br>Share</a></p>
        <p class="menulink" id="menulink2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" /><img src="images/start.png" alt="Start" /><br>Start</a></p>
        <p class="menulink-btn"><a href="#" id="load"/><img src="images/settings.png" alt="Settings" /><br>Settings</a></p>
        <!--<a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>-->
        </div><!--end panelholder-->
    </div><!--panel -->

<!--Content2 from panel-->
<div data-role="page" id="p2"><!--start #p2-->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content"><!-- start ui-content-->
       <div id="panelholder2"> <!--start #panelholder2-->
        <div style="overflow:hidden;"><img src="images/back.png" alt="back" class="set-img"/><span class="set-align">settings</span></div>
      <div id="list-container">  <!--start list-container-->
      <ul id="panel2-list">
      <li class="p2-list"><a href="#">refer work</a></li>
      <li class="p2-list"><a href="#">potential link 2</a></li>
      <li class="p2-list"><a href="#">potential link 3</a></li>
      <li class="p2-list"><a href="#">potential link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>  <!--end list-container-->
      <div class="clearfloat"></div>
      <div id="dashboard"><!--start dashboard-->
      <div class="dbimg" id="link1"><a><img src="images/network.png"  alt="network" />network</a></div>

      </div><!--End dashboard-->

       </div> <!--end #panelholder2-->
    </div><!-- end ui-content-->

</div><!--end #p2--> 
</div>





<!--#########################Bx slider#########################-->

<!--<section class="row col-lg-10" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">-->

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/banner1.png" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/banner1.png" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/banner1.png" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
<!--</section>  -->            



<!--######################### End Swipe Carousel ##############################-->

<!--</div>-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: true,
  auto: true,
  touchEnabled: true,
  oneToOneTouch: true,
  controls: false,
  pager: false,
  speed: 200
});

});

</script>

<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(document).on("swipe", "#demo-page", function (e) {
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        //if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" )
        if ($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open" &&  $(e.target).closest(".bxslider").length === 0) {
            if (e.type === "swipe") {
                $("#right-panel").panel("open");
            } else if (e.type === "swipe") {
                $("#left-panel").panel("open");
            }
        }

    });
});


</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#load").on("click", function () {
            var items = $("#p2 .ui-content").contents();
            $(this).after(items);
            $("#menulink1, #menulink2, #menulink3, #load").hide();
        });
    });
</script>





               <!--######################### End Swipe Carousel ##############################-->










</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your page structure isn't correct. You shouldn't place a page doc inside another, remove inner page div. panel shouldn't be wrapped in any other div but page div, move it out of content div.

Comment: Thanks lot Omar, I found what was issue just after putting question, I have not warped the bxslider in page.